# How do you stop Intellij from reformating one line Ruby functions?

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea

I have a ruby function like this in one of my tests:

```
def inject_exceptions(_) ; end
```

Intellij keeps reformating the function to look like this:

```
def inject_exceptions(_)
  ;
end
```

How do I configure it to stop doing that?

Comment: Are you looking for a structural formatting setting for all one line ruby methods, or is it just one method/occurrence that you want it to stop formatting?

Comment: maybe https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html

Comment: I want it to stop reformatting all inline function declarations.

Answer (score 1):

To stop IntelliJ from formatting a specific piece of code you can enable "Formatter Control" under:

Preferences -> Editor -> Code style

Tick the checkbox for `Enable formatter markers in comments`

And then wrap your code with:

```
# @formatter:off
def inject_exceptions(_) ; end
# @formatter:on
```

This works in any language, just make sure to put the markers in a comment.

Comment: This is not a great solution as you need to code for the IDE.

Comment: I totally agree, unfortunately I don't know of a better option for you.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it's not possible to configure it, but please follow the corresponding request:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-21387

Comment: Thanks, I +1'd that on your site.

Comment: Going to leave this question open until the jetbrains fix is out.